# Multi line processing Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to process multi line dataset using Spark structured streaming. Sample dataset is given below

```
{"reqID":"id3", "time":1577085247000, "type":"start"}                                 
{"reqID":"id3", "time":1577085250000, "type":"sysstart"}                                 
{"reqID":"id3", "time":1577085256000, "type":"sysend"}                                 
{"reqID":"id3", "time":1577085260000, "type":"end"}                                 
{"reqID":"id4", "time":1577085263000, "type":"start"}                                 
{"reqID":"id4", "time":1577085266000, "type":"sysstart"}                                 
{"reqID":"id4", "time":1577085269000, "type":"sysend"}                                 
{"reqID":"id4", "time":1577085278000, "type":"end"}
```

I want to perform operations like `end_time(time for type end) - start_time(type for type start)` based on `reqID`.

I have tried grouping by `reqID` and I am able to merge the events during aggregation but the merged events are in `ArrayType` and I couldn't able to perform the required operations.

As an alternate approach I have tried pivoting but it is not working for streaming. It is working only for batch.

What will be solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with the where and join conditions, selecfting the pieces you want, joining them and operating as desired:

```
df.where($"type" === "start")
  .drop("type")
  .withColumnRenamed("time", "startTime")
  .join(df.where($"type" === "end")
          .drop("type")
          .withColumnRenamed("time", "endTime"), "reqID")
  .withColumn("result", $"endTime" - $"startTime")
```

**Output**

```
+-----+-------------+-------------+------+
|reqID|    startTime|      endTime|result|
+-----+-------------+-------------+------+
|  id3|1577085247000|1577085260000| 13000|
|  id4|1577085263000|1577085278000| 15000|
+-----+-------------+-------------+------+
```